# how does mysqli stmt fetch_object() return objects of specified class?

Tags: php, mysqli, casting

I've uploaded my php scripts to my hosted Web site, but there is a problem.
There is no `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` function on it. (*I cant do anything about it*)

I found that there is a way around that using `bind_result()` and `fetch()`, 
but I need functionality from the standard `fetch_object()` function.

I need to get objects of a specified type.

How does `fetch_object()` return objects of a specified type, 
or how can I cast an array from `fetch()` to specified class without too much effort?

P.S. I can add constructors to all classes with array as argument, but is there is an easier way?